# How do I send test emails from Bugzilla?

Tags: bugzilla

I'm using Bugzilla 5.0.2.  It wasn't sending emails, so I changed some parameters and now I'd like to test it.  I set `mail_delivery_method` to `Test`, now what should I do to prompt Bugzilla to send an email? This sounds like a too-simple question, but I can't find anything obvious no matter where I look.

Answer (score 0):

By default Bugzilla doesn't send emails to the person doing the action since they obviously know they did it.

So to send an email create a bug and assign it to someone other than yourself.

Alternatively go to Preference then click the Email Preferences tab and make sure you get emails for all activity.

Comment: I've changed my email preferences to all three of Assignee/Reporter/CCed for "I want to receive email when: A new bug is created".  Still, when I create a test bug, I get the message "Email sent to: no one" and I receive no email.  Is there no way for an administator to test the most persistently difficult part of Bugzilla to get working without sending bothersome test bugs to other people?

Comment: Did you uncheck all the options in the "but not when (overrides above):" section?